# want to insert values in mysql database using stored procedure

Tags: mysql, adapter, ibm-mobilefirst

I have created a mysql adapter in my worklight 6.0
And I want to insert data in mydql database using stored procedure addproduct.can anybody tell me that what will be the javascript to call the procedure.

My main.js file

```
    function wlCommonInit(){

    }

    function addProductRec()

     {

    var validate = true;

   var query = {};

   if ($("#prod_name").val() != "") {
        query.productName = $("#prod_name").val();
   } else {
        validate = false; 
        alert("invalid");
   }

   if ($("#prod_model").val() != "") {
        query.Model = $("#prod_model").val();
   } else {
        validate = false; 
   }

   if ($("#prod_qty").val() != "") {
        query.Qty = $("#prod_qty").val();
   } else {
        validate = false;
   }

   if ($("#prod_price").val() != "") {
        query.price = $("#prod_price").val();
   } else {
        validate = false;

   }

   if (validate) {
       var queryData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(query));

       WL.Client.invokeProcedure({
                adapter : "Product",
  procedure : "addProduct",
  parameters : [ queryData.productName, queryData.Qty,
                      queryData.Model, queryData.price ]
  }, {
                  onSuccess : function(result) {
                  $.mobile.changePage("#list", {
          transition : "slide",
   reverse : false,
   changeHash : false
           });
                  alert("added");
  },
    onFailure : failureCallback

  });
 } else {
            alert("All fields required");
 }
}
```

My adapter.js

```
    var addStatement = WL.Server.createSQLStatement("insert into product "+
    " (productName, Qty, Model, price) values (?, ?, ?, ?)");

    function addProduct(productName,Qty,Model,price) {

return WL.Server.invokeSQLStatement({
    preparedStatement : addStatement,
    parameters : [productName,Qty,Model,price]
});
```

}

Comment: Add your current code.

Comment: It seems to me like you've done it? You have the client code to invoke the adapter procedure and you have the adapter function to insert the data to the database. What exactly are you asking...?

Comment: But when I invoke the adapter it stores the values in database. But when I run it on mobile simulator and submit values it goes to callback failure.

Comment: Is your device/simulator connected to the same network as the server?

Comment: Yes , it is on same network. It is on localhost.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why Jiachen's answer was removed, it was the correct answer and even confirmed so by the question's author in the comments!

To repeat:

> If your build target is "localhost" then it won't work on an Android or iOS simulator or device because it has a different IP even if it runs on "localhost".

Change the server's host from "localhost" to an actual IP address and re-build the project. The IP address will propagate to the device's wlclient.properties/worklight.plist file, where the server connection information is stored. Also double-verify that both the device and server *are on the same network*.